# JFFTPack - get frequency

Tags: java, fft, fftpack

For those of you that have used jfftpack, is there a way to calcuate the frequency from the information recieved from it's RealDoubleFFT.ft() command?
It produces a wave table that can be used to graph the fft, but I need to get the frequency from it also

```
private RealDoubleFFT transformer;
double[] toTransform= raw data sent from short[] to the double[]
transformer.ft(toTransform);
```

Comment: In general, there is not one frequency component.  There is only one if you inject a sine wave.  And even then, this will be smeared out unless you use a suitable window function.  But in general, you should search for the peak absolute value in your output.

Comment: So with my table, i search for larges abs value. can I take this as magnitude and then run frequency = sampleRate * magnitude/sample size

Comment: No, the magnitude is the magnitude of that component.  You want the bin index.  (Note that in general, your frequency will not line up exactly with a bin centre, so you will need to to use interpolation to determine a more precise estimate of frequency).

Comment: I see. How do I calculate the magnitude then. I know that it is sqrt(im*im + re*re) however, only one result lays in this variable

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking; you do that calculation for every element in the output, and pick the biggest...

Comment: I am not sure where the real and imaginary numbers lay in the table. unlike Jtransform, it doesnt provide the real and imaginary next to each other.

Comment: As far as I can see, the FFT methods dump their output into a `Complex1D` object, which contains a real and imaginary array.

Comment: And What parts do I use then. I'm sorry for these questions, but I am confused about it's out put

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer that; are you familiar with what an FFT actually does?  If not, then it's going to be hard to take this explanation much further ;)

Comment: I have experience with them already, it is just this particular library. I have run the method, and now I have an array with the output. given this, what part is the real and what part is the imaginary. I have used Jtransforms which places the real at i and imaginary at i+1. I am not sure if this is simalar or not

Comment: Take a look at the `Complex1D` class; real and imaginary are in two separate arrays.

Comment: I see. but by running the .ft(double[] data) those arrays arent passed back. I am looking for a way to get those arrays

Comment: Oh, if you're talking about the `ComplexDoubleFFT` class, the Javadocs say exactly what the relationship is...

Comment: I am using the RealDoubleFFT class

Comment: Did you look at the Javadocs for that?

Comment: I have had a look. I am going to supply the code I have used to get it above. I am still unsure of the location of the real and imaginary though